# RecyclerView Not showing Message List Properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was Implementing the chat application, and I am using RecyclerView to deal with sender and receiver messages, all things are working except my Chat activity UI,
when sender send the message then received message shown by scrolling down the activity,
Its look like sender message is on one screen and receiver message is on another screen that become visible when is scroll down the screen.

```
    messageList = findViewById(R.id.messageList);
    messageList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    messageList.setLayoutManager(llm);
    messageList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

here `messageList` is the list the contains both of sender and receiver messages.

here is adapter code

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<Message> messages;

private static final int VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1 = 1;
private static final int VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2 = 2;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder

public static class ViewHolder_Type1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mymessageTextView, mytimeTextView;

    public ViewHolder_Type1(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.mymessageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mymessageTextView);
        this.mytimeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mytimeTextView);
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder_Type2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView messageTextView, timeTextView;
    public ViewHolder_Type2(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.messageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        this.timeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
    this.context = context;
    this.messages = messages;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    switch (viewType) {
        // create a new view
        case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mymessage, parent, false);
            ViewHolder_Type1 vh1 = new ViewHolder_Type1(v);
            return vh1;
        case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message, parent, false);
            ViewHolder_Type2 vh2 = new ViewHolder_Type2(v);
            return vh2;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1:
            ViewHolder_Type1 viewholder1 = (ViewHolder_Type1) holder;
            TextView mytimeView = (TextView) viewholder1.mytimeTextView;
            mytimeView.setText(messages.get(position).getTime());
            TextView mymsgView = (TextView) viewholder1.mymessageTextView;
            mymsgView.setText(messages.get(position).getMessage());
            break;
        case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2:
            ViewHolder_Type2 viewholder2 = (ViewHolder_Type2) holder;
            TextView timeView = (TextView) viewholder2.timeTextView;
            timeView.setText(messages.get(position).getTime());
            TextView msgView = (TextView) viewholder2.messageTextView;
            msgView.setText(messages.get(position).getMessage());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you mean , the received messages don't show up ,only if you scroll down?

Comment: please post the adapter code

Comment: yes i received messages but not shown until i scroll down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the problem.

i had created two resource file one for sender message and one for receiver message the root element of these file had `match-parent` width and height,
i just replace it with `wrap-content` now all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to notify your adapter always when you get new messages , and when you scroll you make the recycler re-draw with new info. So put

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

when you want to load new messages

Comment: when message send button clicked then i notify the adapter

Comment: Message message = new Message("", messString, true, new Date());
                    messages.add(message);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    messageText.setText("");